# How would I move a standalone Ubuntu Server to an virtual server (ESXi)

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, migration

I need to move an ubuntu server to a virtual server and everything on it with users, etc. The most logical way would be to move the entire HDD to an virtual disk on VMWare ESXi but how would I do that? Exporting all data, all userdata, configurations, etc seems like an unnecessary hassle. Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [VMWare Converter Standalone](https://www.vmware.com/tryvmware/?p=converter) (i.e. free) version.

Comment: Seems like what I'm looking for, I'm going to have to test that out. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: I've tried to use VMWare Converter Standalone using this guide: http://www.vladan.fr/how-to-p2v-linux-into-vmware-esx-server/ but I'm stuck at step 10, first it complains about a certificate then I've tried both installing and ignoring the certificate but I just get a connection error and can't proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ignoring is the right option, are you sure you've put in the right IP for the host and the local root account and password? I'm no expert at this sorry as I have the 'full' licenced version - perhaps someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the right IP, I get some sort of connection error. It's probably RICOH who've blocked the traffic even tho they say that they've allowed it on the network, problem is I can't have any downtime on the server so I can't take it out of the network temporarily, hopefully it will be fixed next week, otherwise I'll have to try to fix it somehow.